# Why am I getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu

```
db.movie.insert({
    _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c), 
    title: "MongoDB Overview", 
    description: "MongoDB is no sql database", 
    by: "tutorials point", 
    url: "http://www.tutorialspoint.com", 
    tags: ["mongodb", "database", "NoSQL"], 
    likes: 100 
})
```

Comment: `ObjectId(7df78ad8902c)` does not look like a valid thing.

Comment: It is a hexadecimal value. Isn't it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's a Mongo thing, irrc

Comment: @SterlingArcher: ObjectId is a mongo thing, but this construct is totally invalid.

Comment: @AmanAgarwal: no it's not.

Comment: That's true, I think it's generated automagically by mongo. However, a normal object is valid, it doesn't have to be JSON. You're not wrong, of course, I just don't think JSON is relevant here

Comment: How to then add an object id?

Comment: @SterlingArcher: Ah, right. Never mind my json comment. I've got badly burnt by this several years ago, still hurts :)

Comment: @AmanAgarwal MongoDB handles that upon insert.

Comment: db.movie.find().pretty()
{ title: "MongoDB Overview", 
description: "MongoDB is no sql database", 
by: "tutorials point", 
url: "http://www.tutorialspoint.com", 
tags: ["mongodb", "database", "NoSQL"], 
likes: 100 }
There is some problem with this!

Comment: @SterlingArcher This `_id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c)` property looks like possibly valid Mongo *output* (with a stylized `ObjectId` representation that is not valid JavaScript syntax), but it does not look like valid Mongo *input*. When I add quotes in this example, I get a different error (about the id being the wrong length) and when I fix that error, it works fine.

Comment: @AmanAgarwal: If you're using mongoskin, try creating your ObjectId like this: `var mongoID = require('mongoskin').ObjectID; new mongoID('7df78ad8902c');`

Answer (score 0):

(maybe I do not understand your problem) but If You want to set you id . you can make something like this:

```
db.movie.insert({ _id: "7df78ad8902c",      title: "MongoDB Overview",...
```